# YouTube Live API time zone for scheduled broadcasts is wrong

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Dear Google engineers,

Long time ago, when I was just starting with YouTube live API I noticed it is impossible to set a correct starting time for a live event.
Therefore I have picked a working solution, for some reason setting UTC time helped, but in the admin area it was showing a US -7 hours timezone. I did not pay attention to it.

Recently you added a time display for live broadcasts over the event's video window, it is shown before the planned start. This time display is wrong and now I need to manually change this time for every video, via a YouTube interface.

A question: what time format should I send to the API, so it sets correct time for my time zone both for the actual broadcast and for the overlay on top of the video. Is it possible? (Ukraine, UTC+3).

Comment: This is a common problem, it doesn't seem to matter what time format you submit, the YouTube API converts the date submitted to Pacific Time.

2017-09-30T12:00:00Z
2017-09-30T14:00:00+02:00

The above dates all get converted to Pacific time (2017-09-30T05:00:00-07:00) even though they are formatted correctly as ISO 8601 dates.